# Backup and Restore on Debian 9 or Ubuntu 16 destroys "svnversion" performance

Tags: linux, backup, svn

Is there any way to back up and restore a filesystem that doesn't upset `svnversion`.

If I try the following set of operations:

1. Check out a big SVN repository, and build the code
2. Back up the SVN checkout folder
3. Restore the SVN checkout to another location

Then the time to run `svnversion` on the backed up and restored copy is hugely more than on the original:

```
$ cd original_directory
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
$ time svnversion
real    0m5.204s
user    0m0.486s
sys     0m0.698s
$ cd backed_up_and_restored_directory
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
$ time svnversion
real    1m55.846s
user    0m2.813s
sys     0m5.653s
```

The `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` is to clear the Linux cache so I am measuring "from cold". A second `svnversion` in either folder takes a fraction of a second.

I am seeing the same sort of result for all the backup technologies I have tried so  far (`tar`, `rsync`, and ext4 `dump`/`restore`). I am also seeing similar behaviour across a variety of file systems (ext4, btrfs, gluster), and Linux distributions (Debian 8, Debian 9 and Ubuntu 16.04)

In answer to Gerard's question, a couple of example backup/restore commands:

**rsync:**

```
rsync -x -aH --whole-file --delete source_directory/ destination_directory
```

**dump/restore:**

```
dump 0uaf backup_file.dump .
restore -rf backup_file.dump
```

I assume this is happening because the restored files and subdirectories are being stored on the disk in a different order, which is making `svnversion` run very inefficiently on the copy.

Has anyone else experienced this, and does anyone know of a Linux backup/restore technique that will keep the files and directories "in the same order" to prevent this issue?

Comment: Care to show us the commands your using to backup and restore?  I'm not worried about order, but access and modification times of files and folders.

Comment: I've added some example backup and restore commands to the question details

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to retain modification times, eg. with rsync

```
rsync -t -x -aH --whole-file --delete source_directory/ destination_directory
```

Comment: Definitely not that. First, "-a" already implies "-t". Second, I've tried three different backup/restore commands with the same result.

Comment: Is your "destination" on disks that are very much slower?

Comment: No. As I've already said several times, I'm 100% sure it is not the timestamps that are the issue. I can see (from 'ls -i') that the file orders are different, which I am pretty sure is what is causing this problem.